# What is the inverse Laplace transform of squared denominator term?

Tags: laplace-transform

Referring to the image below, what would the inverse Laplace transform be? I can't seem to find any tables that include this case.

[image]

Comment: https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceXform/InvLaplace/InvLaplaceXformPFE.html

You know how to perform partial fraction expansion ?

Comment: [This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) has it all, you just have to fill in the numbers.

Comment: @Ben: Partial fractions don't really help here. You can't split a double pole into two single poles.

Comment: Yeah you're right... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite straightforward to solve. Either just use [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) where you can directly find the corresponding result, or "derive" it yourself with very basic knowledge of the Laplace transform.

You should know that

$$\mathcal{L}\{u(t)\}=\frac{1}{s}\tag{1}$$

Integration is equivalent to multiplication with $1/s$, so integrating $(1)$ gives

$$\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot u(t)\}=\frac{1}{s^2}\tag{2}$$

Replacing $s$ by $s+a$ is equivalent to multiplication with $e^{-at}$. Consequently, we have

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{2}{(s+2)^2}\right\}=2\,t\,e^{-2t} u(t)\tag{3}$$